# TextBox.LineCount and TextBox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex() is always -1 when using MVVM pattern on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a TabControl in my View, and I dynamically add TabItems which contains a textbox as a content. And when want to get Line Count from Selected Item, it always returns -1, also with textbox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex(). Code is below:

My View:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="385" Margin="5,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="740" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{ Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- this is the header template-->
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox
                Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High }" AcceptsReturn="True" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.TextChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 </TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

My ViewModel:

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
tabItem.Header = mainModel.Header;
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = mainModel.TextFile;

tabItem.LayoutUpdated += (sender2, e2) => textBox_LayoutUpdated(sender2, e2);
textBox.LayoutUpdated += (sender3, e3) => textBox_LayoutUpdated(sender3, e3);
tabItem.Content = textBox;
Tabs.Add(tabItem);
SelectedTab = tabItem;

private void textBox_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 lineCount = ((SelectedTab as TabItem).Content as TextBox).LineCount;
}
```

MainModel is my Model in MVVM.

My View.cs:

```
this.UpdateLayout();
TabItem tab = this.tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
int index = ((this.tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem).Content as TextBox).GetLastVisibleLineIndex();
```

Even here in View.cs is always -1;

I am new in WPF MVVM,

Thanks.

Comment: If -1 is being returned it means that the `TextBox` layout information is unavailable. Have you put a breakpoint in your `LayoutUpdated` function to see if it's actually being called?

Comment: You're doing the check before there's anything there. Defer the call or pick a better event to drive it.

Comment: Yes, I have a breakpoint there and it is hit when I make scroll event, then I call UpdateLayout() in that event handler. And, I first add a TabItem to TabControl, and then when I scroll through textbox I need to see LineCount and Last Visible Line Index. But they are always -1, even with calling UpdateLayout() on TabItem in scroll event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You have many issues with your current code. It seems that you actually missed the point of MVVM.

First of all, a view-model must not be aware of the view, nor any view-specific types (e.g. `TabItem`). A view-model is just a layer that adopts your model in such way that this model can be presented by the view. A view-model must not construct the view itself, as you do it in your example.

The reason why you get -1 is that the `TextBox` you add into the tab item will never be laid out, because you override the tab item's `ContentTemplate`.

There are some other things you're either doing wrong or they're unnecessary:

- `Binding` for the tab control's `ItemsSource` must not be `TwoWay`, because the tab control itself will never update this property value. The `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not needed here for the same reason.
- `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not needed for the `SelectedItem` binding, because it has by default the `PropertyChanged` mode
- you have a command named `TextChanged`, but by convention it has to be named `TextChangedCommand` (with a `Command` postfix)
- `tabItem.LayoutUpdated += (sender2, e2) => textBox_LayoutUpdated(sender2, e2)` is an overkill for an event subscription that creates an unnecessary lambda capturing `this`, use the method group syntax instead: `tabItem.LayoutUpdated += textBox_LayoutUpdated`

### And now the true MVVM solution:

Suppose you have the item's view-model:

```
class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    public Item(string header, string textFile)
    {
        Header = header;
        this.textFile = textFile;
    }

    public string Header { get; }

    private string textFile;
    public string TextFile
    {
        get => textFile;
        set { textFile = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int lineCount;
    public int LineCount
    {
        get => lineCount;
        set { lineCount = value; OnPropertyChanged(); Debug.WriteLine("Line count is now: " + value); }
    }
}
```

This view-model represents a single item that will be displayed as a tab item. But maybe this will be some other control in the future - actually you don't have to bother with that. The view-model has no idea which controls **exactly** will display the values. The view-model just provides these values in a convenient way.

So, the `Header` and the `TextFile` properties contain the model values. The `LineCount` property will be calculated by the view (more on that see below).

The main view-model for that would look like this:

```
class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    private Item selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set { selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Note that the `Items` collection property is read-only. That means no one can change the reference to the collection, but the collection itself is not read-only. The `SelectedItem` reference may be updated however.

And now the important point: the `LineCount` property of the `TextBox` will also be updated, e.g. when the `TextBox` wraps the text and the control is resized. So we can't just calculate the lines count in view-model, we need to do this in the view.

However, the view-model, as we know, must not be aware of the view. What to do? In such cases a good developer prefers a `Behavior` from the `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace.

Let's create a simple behavior that will monitor the `LineCount` of a `TextBox`:

```
class LineCountBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public int LineCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LineCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LineCountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineCountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LineCount", typeof(int), typeof(LineCountBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += RefreshLineCount;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += RefreshLineCount;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= RefreshLineCount;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= RefreshLineCount;
    }

    private void RefreshLineCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      LineCount = AssociatedObject.LineCount;
    }
}
```

Now we can attach this behavior to any `TextBox` and use the behavior's `LineCount` dependency property as a binding source. Here is a full XAML setup:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />          
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TextFile, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:LineCountBehavior LineCount="{Binding LineCount, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

So this is a 'clean' MVVM solution. Hope I could give you some insights.

BTW, I don't know why you need this line count in the view-model...

Comment: The namespace is now `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors` instead of `System.Windows.Interactivity`. And you need to add `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"` to your XAML.